# How can we resolve Intl reference error in safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript Intl.NumberFormat for showing currency in euro format

```
var formatterPayment = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2
});

formatterPayment.format(amount);
```

In Chrome and Firefox I don't get any errors or warnings but in Safari I am getting this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl

How can I resolve this? Due to this error message other script is also not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Safari are you testing with? It's unsupported in < 10. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am testing with safari for windows. It's version is 5.1.7

Comment: That version of Safari is over 6 years old. It does not support `Intl`. Do you *really* need to support that outdated a version of any browser? Especially one with such a little user base as Safari?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks I will test with latest version of safari and come back

Comment: 5.1.7 is the latest version of Safari for Windows. Apple have stopped releasing it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Okay got it. I will check it in mac and come back. Thank you.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Today I checked with mic and latest safari. There is no issue with `Intl`. Thank you

Comment: The issue persist  on mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Polyfill Library](https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/features/) to support that feature for older browsers

```
Example:
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

[Examples](https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/examples)